# How to multiply a first key value in second key value and then remove the second key, in array of objects for each elemnts?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I want to multiply a first key value in second key value and then remove the second key for each object element.

I have an array like this:

```
[
    { id:1, price:2, amount:4, numberBuy: 3 },
    { id:2, price:3, amount:5, numberBuy: 2 },
]
```

and after that have to become like this:

```
[
    { id:1, price:2, amount:12 },
    { id:2, price:3, amount:10 },
]
```

I strictly love to using it by map method if its possible maybe your method can help me even in learning it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `map` and return each modified object.

```
const newArray = [
  { id: 1, price: 2, amount: 4, numberBuy: 3 },
  { id: 2, price: 3, amount: 5, numberBuy: 2 }
].map(({ id, price, amount, numberBuy}) => ({
  id,
  price,
  amount: amount * numberBuy,
}));
```